# Any way to use an Android-provided class if on Android, and a different one if not?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developing a Java library that I want to use both in Android and on desktops. Android provides the `android.database.sqlite` class, which I'd like to use, but which obviously isn't available on desktop systems. (It's the only Android dependency.)

I'm fairly new to Java. If this were C or C++, I'd use different versions of a wrapper class to access SQLite, depending on the platform. Is something like that possible in Java, and if so, how? Is that the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface DbAccessLibrary  ..

public class AndroidDbAccessLibrary implements DbAccessLibrary  ..

public class DesktopDbAccessLibrary implements DbAccessLibrary  ..

DbAccessLibrary accessLibrary;
try {
    getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase");
    accessLibrary = new AndroidDbAccessLibrary();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    accessLibrary = new DesktopDbAccessLibrary();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be portable you cannot use `android.database.sqlite` directly, You have to hide it behind an interface as @msh suggested. Instead of inventing you own interface you can use an existing interface for this: **java-jdbc**:

I have created a portable android/java-se library that converts between csv and sqlite database.

The library initialisation gets a jdbc-driver (java.sql.Driver) that allows access to the other jdbc interfaces (Connection, Statement, ....)

You can use [org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid) an opensource android jdbc driver on the android side and org.sqlite.JDBC on the java-se-side.

I had problems with using the jdbc driver-manager on the android side so i used 
`new org.sqldroid.SQLDroidDriver()` on the android clientside instead to initialize the library

My portable library ended with 3 libs:

- one portable lib containing the csv/sql stuff and interfaces that hide implementation differences between android and java-se as described by @msh -s answer
- one android specific implementation of the interfaces and
- one java-se specific implementation of the interfaces.

Currently the platform specific part has only logging stuff (implemented by log4j or android logging).

the csv lib work great on both platforms since integration testing on the java-se is much easier than on the android side. This is a technical lib.

However i have failed to put business-code into a shared lib. many android api-s depend on the android-sandbox (Context) where activity, broadcast,... are inherited from and that do  not exist in java-se.